# Populate a viewmodel with a newly added database ID

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

This is a follow up to a question that was asked yesterday.

I have a viewmodel, which shows a list of objectives.  Using jquery I can add a new objectives line to the screen (the ID is set to 0 for any new objectives listed).  When I click on the Save button to Post the objective list back to the controller, the controller loops through the objective list, and checks the ID against the database.  If the ID is NOT found, it creates a new objective, adds this to the DB context, and saves te changes. It then retreives the ID, and returns the View(model) to the View.

The problem is, although the ID in the model, is updated to the database ID - when the model is rendered in the View again, it's ID is still 0.  So if I click Save again, it again, re-adds the "new objective added previously" to the database again.

My controller is shown below:

```
    //
    // POST: /Objective/Edit/model
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(ObjectivesEdit model)
    {
        if (model.Objectives != null)
        {
             foreach (var item in model.Objectives)
            {
                // find the database row
                Objective objective = db.objectives.Find(item.ID);
                if (objective != null) // if database row is found...
                {
                    objective.objective = item.objective;
                    objective.score = item.score;
                    objective.possscore = item.possscore;
                    objective.comments = item.comments;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                else // database row not found, so create a new objective
                {
                    Objective obj = new Objective();
                    obj.comments=item.comments;
                    obj.objective = item.objective;
                    obj.possscore = item.possscore;
                    obj.score = item.score;
                    db.objectives.Add(obj);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    // now get the newly created ID 
                    item.ID = obj.ID;
                 }
             }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

My ID is being set in the controller:

[image]

**EDIT: Another example here, showing model.Objectives[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBRhv.png).ID being updated:**

[image]

However when the view renders it, it reverts to 0:

[image]

The Objectives list is determined as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcObjectives2.Models
    {
    public class ObjectivesEdit
    {
        public IEnumerable<Objective> Objectives { set; get; }
        public ObjectivesEdit()
        {
            if (Objectives == null)
                Objectives = new List<Objective>();
        }
    }
    }
```

The View has:

```
@model MvcObjectives2.Models.ObjectivesEdit

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Objectives)
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Save</button>
 }
```

and in my EditorTemplate (objective.cshtml):

```
@model  MvcObjectives2.Models.Objective          

<div class="objec">
<div>
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.objective})
</div>
<div>
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.score})
</div>
<div>
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.possscore})
</div>
<div>
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.comments})

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)  // This is the ID where it should now show the new ID from the database, but shows 0

</div>
</div>
```

I suspect the issue is somewhere in my controller - but I would appreciate any advise on how to get my View to render the new ID of the added objective.

Comment: It's very likely that your newly created object doesn't have an ID yet, it gets created in the database and that information probably isn't push to the object.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you don't use your editor template and actually render the markup in a loop?

Comment: Hi @SteenT - that is wht the changes are saved to the database, and then the ID retreieved: db.SaveChanges(); 
                    // now get the newly created ID  
                    item.ID = obj.ID;

Comment: Have you debugged this? And made sure that the ID property has been populated?

Comment: When you set item.ID to the new ID, is that reflected in the Model.Objectives[n].ID for that item?

Comment: Hi @SteenT - yes - please see the first screenshot above - where it shows the new ID.

Comment: Hi @podiluska - yes - that is what the first screenshot shows above

Comment: @simon-whitehead - if I redirect to a view showing a normal list (index for example), then it renders correctly.

Comment: @fixit That looks like it's showing the value of "item", not of Model.Objectives[n]?

Comment: Hi - I've added another screenshot showing model.Objectives[1].ID with the new ID value populated.

Comment: It appears that any property changed in the controller, eg: obj.comments= "this has been updated in the contoller"; will still render whatever was Posted to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After rewording my search, I came across several posts which say this is by design.  A Posted form expects to display what it sent to the controller, if the same page is shown again.

However, you can add this, which will flush ModelState, and apparantly show the updated values from the model, updated in the controller:

```
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View(model);
```

I'm not certain if this has any other effect yet - but for now, it appears to work ok.

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 1):

The Html.HiddenFor has bitten me before in a similar scenario. The problem is when using this Html helper the hidden value is not updated on the re-post.

If you post something from the form and change it inside your controller, when you re-render the page using it will use the value which was originally posted to the action.

Instead use

```
<input type="hidden" name="ID" id="ID" value="@Html.Encode(Model.ID)" />
```

Comment: Hi - the view then loses the ability to render the Objective as a list, so the name and id attributes of the field, just render as "ID" and not (eg) id="Objectives_0__ID" name="Objectives[0].ID" - so the model loses the [ref] - is there a way around that?

Comment: In that case just make sure to line up the Id and Name values of the hidden to be the same as your model so the HTTPPOST will correctly bind them to the model. Alternatively you could create your own HtmlHelper that will render the hidden correctly and use the name of object that your on.

Comment: Hi - sorry, I'm not certain what you mean - how would I generate the ID and Name correctly, to allow the view to populate id="Objectives_0__ID" name="Objectives[0].ID" and then id="Objectives_1__ID" name="Objectives[1].ID" within the view?

Comment: Even if I render as an textbox, the value still remains 0.

Comment: It appears that any property changed in the controller, eg: obj.comments= "this has been updated in the contoller"; will still render whatever was Posted to it.  Not just hidden fields for some reason.

Comment: You may need to construct a new object and pass it to your view. You may want to employ a Clone() method for this. Also I have had to use the following trick with the value to force the Razor engine to render the value correctly for a hidden value. value="@Html.Encode(Model.ID)". Odd I know but a trick that has worked for me. Please mark as an answer if you find this works for you too.